# No Deep Link Data

Tags: branch.io

In May we created a proof of concept App using Branch.io. Back then it worked but now coming back to prepare for release, it does not work. We dont get any Deep Link Data. We do get the following:

```
[BNCServerInterface.m:240] returned = Status: 200; Data: {
    "branch_view_enabled" = 0;
    "browser_fingerprint_id" = "<null>";
    data = "{\"+is_first_session\":true,\"+clicked_branch_link\":false}";
    "device_fingerprint_id" = xxx;
    "identity_id" = xxx;
    link = "https://2elk.test-app.link/?%24identity_id=xxx";
    "session_id" = xxx;
}
```

The link is created in "Marketing".
The link is from Test and in code `Branch *branch = [Branch getTestInstance];`

Have you come across something like this. Could it have something to do with dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: this could be a key mismatch, since the `+clicked_branch_link` param is returning false. Could you check and make sure you are using the right test/live Branch key for the link?

Also note if you hit the base domain directly (e.g., `2elk.test-app.link`) there *won't* be any link data because that isn't technically a Branch link.

Comment: " there won't be any link data because that isn't technically a Branch link." What would be a correct branch link ?

Comment: @CedricSoubrie something like `2elk.test-app.link/mylinkslug` or `2elk.test-app.link/VmfA6MG8ew`. The base URL by itself has no data attached — you need that additional link slug (either custom or randomly generated)

Comment: @AlexBauer, i am also facing same issue, and if app not installed in device, its not redirecting to appstore app, can u give suggestions for this, i am facing this from 3 days :(