# Branch.io and Instant Apps

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io, android-instant-apps

I have an app that's using Branch.io and am in process of updating it to support Instant Apps.  Part of this change will require using app links to navigate from one part of app to another.

The Activity that I'm opening is configured to use Branch.io (e.g. using instructions in https://dev.branch.io/marketing-channels/android-instant-apps/guide/) and includes following in it's `onStart()` method.  However I'm not seeing parameters I'm including in deep link in `referringParams`.

```
Branch.getInstance().initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
        Log.d("Branch", "onInitFinished() with deep link data: " + referringParams);
    }
});
```

Do I need to trigger opening of the branch link in particular way from Android code for this to work?

BTW `referringParams` above does show `+clicked_branch_link` being `false`.

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify a few things.  I'm trying for example to launch `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` using app deep link.  `ActivityB` includes `<intent-filter>` as described in https://dev.branch.io/marketing-channels/android-instant-apps/guide/ for example.  In `ActivityA` I'm currently trying to open/create Branch.io link as follows (have also formed link directly, as is used in that `android-instant-apps` sample for example, but that's not considered a "branch link")

```
    HashMap<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    metadata.put(PARAM, param);

    BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject().addContentMetadata(metadata);
    LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties();
    branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(context, linkProperties, (url, error) -> {
        if (error == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If I try to open the url generated (by `generateShortUrl`) directly on device (clicking on link for example) then `ActivityB` is launched and I see the param I included in `initSession` callback.  If I try to open it using code above (navigating betweeen `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` then `ActivityB` is launched but don't get the params (and `+clicked_branch_link` is `false`)

Comment: Key mismatch could cause  `+clicked_branch_link` param to return `false`. Please double check that you set the correct test/live Branch keys (refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763840/no-deep-link-data). Also make sure that the Branch link and key belong to the same Branch app.

Comment: Should branch.io key come in to play in code that's opening the app link?  If so, does that mean that we need some branch specific code to trigger opening the  link?

Comment: To receive the deep link data you need register a deep link router function (override `onNewIntent()` in Activity where you call `initSession`). Then retrieve session parameters by calling `branch.getLatestReferringParams`
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking#initialization

Comment: By “this change will require using app links to navigate from one part of app to another” do you mean you still need to configure your full app to use Branch as Android App Links? If so, you need to complete this guide first https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/android/

Comment: @JuliaK I have followed that guide but still running in to issues....this works when linking directly to ActivityB (e.g. by someone clicking on link) but not when I use link to navigate between ActivityA and ActivityB.

Answer (score 1):

Sojan from Branch here
If you are trying to deep link to a new feature from another **instant app** apk unfortunetely Branch is not supporting this feature now.

If you are trying to get deep link params on opening an activity B in a new feature from activity A from another feature in an installed app you can achieve it in the following way.

ActivityA.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("yourBranchLink"));
intent.putExtra("branch","yourBranchLink");
intent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session",true);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Sojan, I'll give that a go.

Comment: Sojan, achieve this, I should create a quick link at Branch dashboard and use it on Uri.parse("yourBranchLink"), am I right? And then, put a specific Intent Filter in manifest for this link?

Comment: @GuilhermeLimaPereira  You can do it by creating a quick link from dashboard. Also if you are trying to do it form your application, you can generate a Branch link dynamically and use it as explained here. (You need intent filter in the manifest) https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking#creating-a-deep-link

Comment: You mean a specific intent filter for this generated link? I don't get how it would work. Think in this flow: 1. User will click in a branch link which will open my app; 2. My app opens on Splash Activity, which has the logic to redirect the user to the right activity; 3. The splash activity will get the branch parameter and decide that has to open Activity B, which is in another feature module. What would I put on Uri.parse? It doesn't make sense to me on how a dynamically link will lead to the correctly activity without me programming it

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure the Branch SDK with your Instant App supported Android App you can follow the steps below:

**1. Initialize the Branch SDK**
Initialize the Branch SDK in the onCreate() method of your Application class. If you plan on deep linking from your Android Instant App to your full Android app after its installed, you'll need to add the line enablePlayStoreReferrer. This adds a delay to the initialization to wait for the Google Play Referrer, which can take up to a second.

```
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  // This is needed to deferred deep link from an Android Instant App to a full app
  // It tells the Branch initialization to wait for the Google Play Referrer before proceeding.
  Branch.enablePlayStoreReferrer(1000L);

  // Initialize the Branch SDK
  Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
}
```

**2. Add your Branch keys and register for Install Referrer**

Instant Apps can be rather confusing as there are many different manifests, but you want to find the Manifest that contains your application tags. Make sure your Application class name is defined here, and then specify the Branch keys inside the application element.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".MyApplication">

<!-- Set to true to use Branch_Test_Key -->
  <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />
  <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_app_live_key" />
  <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test_app_test_key" />

  <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

</application>
```

**3. Configure your Branch links as Android App Links**

Assuming you've already configured Branch for Android App Links for your Android App the next step is to add the intent filter for App links support in your Application Tag. Make sure to replace the `xxxx` with your link Domain. (If you haven't configured your full native app to use Branch as Android App Links you can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/dashboard/integrate/#android) and [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#configure-app).)

```
<application
  ......

  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xxxx.app.link" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xxxx-alternate.app.link" />
  </intent-filter>

</application>
```

**4. Retrieve Branch deep link data**

Add Branch initSession in Activities which are configured to open from a link click in order to receive the deep link params. This will return the deep link data from the referring link.

```
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  Branch.getInstance().initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
      Log.d("Branch","onInitFinished() with deep link data: " + referringParams);
    }
  });
}
```

**5. Configure the deep linking from Instant App to your Full App**

To convert your user who just arrived in your Instant App to your full native app, Branch SDK provides convenient methods to check for app types and full app conversion. This eliminates the dependency on Google IA support SDK ('com.google.android.instantapp'). Here are some of the methods:

`Branch.isInstantApp()`

This convenience method checks whether the current version of app running is Instant App or Full Android App

`Branch.showInstallPrompt()`

This methods shows an install prompt for the full Android app, allowing you an easy way to pass Branch referring deep data to the full app through the install process.

Comment: what's the recommended way for opening of Branch.io app link to be triggered when navigating from one part of app to another?

Comment: I think above is taken directly from https://dev.branch.io/marketing-channels/android-instant-apps/guide/ ?  As mentioned, I had followed these instructions.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly are you still getting +clicked_branch_link: false. Also, do you get the link parameters in your standard app correctly?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly You need to add the App links intent filter in the Application tag not the Activity Tag. As far as I understand, if you have the instant App configuration setup correctly you can use initSession() in ActivityB to read the link parameters correctly when you are routed from instantApp containing ActivityA.

Comment: I noticed that in instructions but believe it's an error.  That's not a valid location for `<intent-filter>` (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) and in fact the Branch.io instant apps sample app doesn't use this approach.

Comment: Also, I'm not having issue if someone clicks on link directly.....issue is when using it to navigate from one part of app to another.